# How to register for Scroll Event on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an app on Windows phone. I want to get notified when the ScrollViewer starts scrolling.
I see some example does this:

```
 ScrollViewer sv;
 sv.OnScrollChanged += ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
```

But the problem is I think the 'OnScrollChanged' properties is not available on Windows phone.

How can I get notified when user starts scrolling on a ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone Runtime or Windows Phone Silverlight?

The Windows.UI.Xaml.ScrollViewer used in Windows Phone Runtime events exposes [ViewChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanging.aspx) and [ViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged.aspx) events.

The Silverlight ScrollViewer doesn't expose any direct events like this, but you could try binding to the [Horizontal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontaloffset(v=vs.105).aspx) or [VerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset(v=vs.105).aspx) properties

Comment: Thanks. I tried ViewChanging. That works when the ScrollViewer is scrollable (i.e. the content height is longer than the scrollViewer height). In that case, when I scroll, the ScrollViewer reaches the end of the list. But what if I am at the top of the list and I still try to scroll up. Visually, I see the ScrollViewer bounce back (since I am already at the top), but I don't get the ViewChanging event. How can I get notified for the 2nd case?